# How use CasperJS in a NodeJS application?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, casperjs

I need run CasperJS commands in a NodeJS application. How do I do it?

For example, if I use only CasperJS a I don't make a file with `fs.writeFile();`

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried researching?

Comment: Yes, but I don't find a solution for this situation.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relavent, but it might be https://github.com/WaterfallEngineering/SpookyJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have written your script in casperjs. then do something like what I do.
export your data in csv/json file as input from your node app
use child_process.spawn to run your casperjs
casperjs script will write a csv/json file as result
import the result in your node app.